# Are there decentralized bitcoin asset management systems out there?

Tags: trust

Are there any decentralized/shared bitcoin asset/investment management systems out there?

It should be applicable to the following case:

Many peers and nobody trusts each other. But trust is gained by investing bitcoins in that system. 
Nobody should be able to withdraw more money, than they invested.

I cross-posted this question on

http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/1zsjr8/are_there_decentralized_bitcoin_asset_management/

I hope it's ok, if not i'll take the link out of this question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that these systems maybe what you are looking for:

[Open Transactions](http://opentransactions.org/wiki/index.php?title=About) -  A general open peer to peer crypto asset system.
[CounterpartyD](https://github.com/PhantomPhreak/counterpartyd) - a New Asset system based on on Cryptocurrency

**EDIT** 20/05/2014

You should also check out NXT Crypto Its looking very promising the system they have developed.